# Does Chinese character recognistion software exist?

Tags: characters

does any one know if there is any method or software to recognize definition, sound of a character? Is there any software?

Comment: like OCR? is that what you mean? or voice recognition? -

Comment: 你題供的三個選擇都不是軟體,所以都不算答案

Answer (score 3):

Pleco is a free Chinese<>English app for iOS and Android which can recognise handwriting (you draw with your finger on screen the chinese characted you want to look up) and give definition and pronunciation (in pinyn, zhuyin, and audio file).

In the payd version there's also OCR, but it isn't very precise.

Comment: The OCR has gotten better recently (at least under iOS).  Still not perfect, but a considerable improvement.  It's still experimental, I think, so it may get another tune-up before it gets its official release in Pleco 4.0.

Comment: I think the handwriting recognition costs a nominal fee.  You can download the app for free and it'll tell you how much the handwriting recognition costs.

Comment: There is an "Enhanced Handwriting Recognition" for which you have to pay, but the free handwriting recognition is already pretty good: of course it doesn't recognize cursive script, while paid one can be set to recognize it.

Comment: Ahh, didn't know that (probably because I paid for the handwriting recognition years ago, possibly when there wasn't a free one).  Nice to know!

Answer (score 1):

I have Hanping Pro and Hanping Camera Apps. Hanping Camera can read a line of Chinese from a text into your phone. Once you have it in your phone, you pick out individual characters and hear them spoken. It can't read a whole text to you. (At least I don't think so.)

It also has that 'draw a character with your finger' capability.

To scan text into my computer I use command line tesseract. I find it very good.

Answer (score 0):

What are the scenarios you are facing? 

If the character can be copied and pasted on a computer, then search in Google/Wikitionary?

If it is in a physical form or you cannot copy it to a computer (e.g. in a book, or signs on the road), you can try **Google Translate mobile app**, it utilises the camera on the phone and that can scan and translate.